# What is the syntax for triggering a click event for clicking on an item in a gallery ribbon control in VB?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

This is for a Microsoft Word add-in I am working on with Visual Studio in VB.

I have a gallery ribbon control (Gallery1) with 4 items (Item0, Item1, etc.).
Normally I handle click events with buttons that are in dropdown controls but would like to use the gallery for these functions. Galleries have buttons too but also have items that display in a format I would like to take advantage of.

For buttons I would use:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
```

And for the gallery control I have tried this:

```
Private Sub Gallery1_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Gallery1.Click
```

but that treats all items in the control the same where instead I want item0 to trigger a different action than item1, etc.

What is the syntax of handling the click of an item in a gallery? Thank you.

Comment: `Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click`

Comment: Think you want to look at the RibbonControlEventArgs.Control property.  From memory that has the actual item clicked, check that property then build conditional operations based on the value

Comment: @evry1falls that is for the button click but I am looking to handle the item click within the gallery control. They are not considered buttons.

Comment: Well, according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbongallery?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), **RibbonGallery** Class doesn't have a **Click** Event, only **MouseClick** Events.

Comment: @evry1falls pardon my ignorance but is that different than the ‘standard’ click?

Comment: What do you mean by **standard** click?

Comment: If you meant, if there is a difference between **MouseClick** and **Click**, then the answer is YES by all means.